# C++ convert/adding char to string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I'm about to hit the screen with my keyboard as I couldn't convert a char to a string, or simply adding a char to a string.

I have an char array and I want to pick whichever chars I choose in the array to create a string. How do I do that?

```
string test = "oh my F**king GOD!"
const char* charArray = test.c_str();

string myWord = charArray[0] + charArray[4];
```

thats how far I got with it. Please help.

Comment: Or you could do `string myWord; myWord += charArray[0]; myWord += charArray[4];` Cat PlusPlus's way is better, I'm just saying that you can use concatenation for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to convert to c_str just:

```
string test = "oh my F**king GOD!";
string myWord;
myWord += test[0];
myWord += test[4];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string myWord;
myWord.push_back(test[0]);
myWord.push_back(test[4]);
```

You don't need to use `c_str()` here.

Comment: There is also `basic_string& operator=(charT c)`. I think I would use that. Like, `myWord += test[0]`.

Comment: @Alf: Missed a `+` in the function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted in some way to use C++ functions only? Because, for this purpose I use the old C functions like sprintf

Comment: **To all passers-by:** Please take the direct opposite of this advice! Quite conversely, you should [generally] use C functions _only_ when you are restricted to them for some legacy reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also need to remember that a C++ string is quite similar to a vector, while a C string is just array of chars. Vectors have an `operator[]` and a push_back method. [Read more here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) You use push_back and do not convert to c string.
So your code would look like this:

```
string test = "oh my F**king GOD!"
string myWord;
myWord.push_back(test[0]);
myWord.push_back(test[4]);
```

Comment: A C++ string is not a vector. A vector is a vector; a string is a string. And it's `operator[]`.